# Server Loading Time Issue

Tags: linux, apache, cpanel

I got an email from my hosting company telling me that there is a loading problem on my server , actually I am not a webmaster so I need your help if that is possible.
they said that :

```
IMPORTANT: Do not ignore this email.
  This is cPanel stats runner on examle.com!
  While processing the log files for user "example", the cpu has been
maxed out for more than a 6 hour period.  The current load/uptime line on the server at the time of
this email is
  18:19:49 up 129 days, 21:47,  0 users,  load average: 4.20, 3.37, 3.16
  You should check the server to see why the load is so high and take
steps to lower the load.  If you want stats to continue to run even with a high load; Edit
/var/cpanel/cpanel.config and change extracpus to a number larger then 0 (run
/usr/local/cpanel/startup afterwards to pickup the changes).
```

I want to know is my server being attacked or it is a problem inside the server (website problem in loading)??
I hope you can help me on this it is an emergency .Thanks

Comment: How do you expect us to tell what's wrong on your server?

Comment: I do not want that I just want to know how I can figure out where is the problem ,I mean is it maybe because cron jobs , I am sorry about my lack of information in webmaster tasks

Comment: There are so many possibilities, it would be impossible to answer in this format.

Comment: SO is the wrong place for this kind of questions. Add some information regarding your system and try it on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahoy,

This email is sent out when the program that process website statistics, has worked on processing your website stats for over 6 hours.  The stats the program is building are under the stats section of cPanel.

This can happen for a various reasons, However the most likely is that your server hosting your cPanel account is overloaded and the processing of your stats was paused while the server was overloaded for over 6 hours causing your stats not to run.

There are other causes for this error including if you use an awstats.conf file, this may be causing issues.

However this issue is something the server administrator will have to address since they need access to specific log files as will as to the server's root shell.

One remedy the server administrator could use is to change extracpus to a number larger then 0 in /var/cpanel/cpanel.config and then running /scripts/restartsrv_cpsrvd

If the above fails the server administrator will have to locate the issue from one of the following log files:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/stats_log
```

A chart of cPanel Log Files and Config files can be found at the links below for further investigation.

- http://go.cpanel.net/configposter
- http://go.cpanel.net/logposter